# Scala(Spark)- how to groupby when columns are list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my Scala program, I have a dataframe with schema as such:

```
root
 |-- FIRST_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LAST_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SEGMENT_EMAIL: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- SEGMENT_ADDRESS_STATE: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- SEGMENT_ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Some sample values are:

```
|FIRST_NAME      |LAST_NAME      |CONFIRMATION_NUMBER|       SEGMENT_EMAIL|SEGMENT_ADDRESS_STATE|SEGMENT_ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE|
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|           Stine|          Rocha|         [48978451]|[Xavier.Vich@gmail..|                 [MA]|               [01545-1300]|
|          Aurora|      Markusson|         [26341542]|                  []|                 [AR]|                    [72716]|
|           Stine|          Rocha|         [29828771]|[Xavier.Vich@gmail..|                 [OH]|               [45101-9613]|
|          Aubrey|      Fagerland|         [24572991]|[Aubrey.Fagerland...|                   []|                         []|
```

How can I GroupBy similar records based on First name + Last name + Email, when the column values are in form of list.

I want the output like this:

```
|FIRST_NAME      |LAST_NAME      |CONFIRMATION_NUMBER  |       SEGMENT_EMAIL|SEGMENT_ADDRESS_STATE|SEGMENT_ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE|
+----------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|           Stine|          Rocha| [48978451, 29828771]|[Xavier.Vich@gmail..|             [MA, OH]|   [01545-1300, 45101-9613]|
|          Aurora|      Markusson|           [26341542]|                  []|                 [AR]|                    [72716]|
|          Aubrey|      Fagerland|           [24572991]|[Aubrey.Fagerland...|                   []|                         []|
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing user define function to merge multiple `Seq` in a single `Seq`. Here is the way how to get the desired output:

**Create input dataframe:** Although datatype of `CONFIRMATION_NUMBER` field is not mentioned in the schema, I've assumed it as integer.

```
import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq(("Stine",  "Rocha", Seq(48978451), Seq("Xavier.Vich@gmail"), Seq("MA"), Seq("01545-1300")),
      ("Aurora", "Markusson", Seq(26341542),Seq(),Seq("AR"),Seq("72716")),
      ("Stine",  "Rocha", Seq(29828771),Seq("Xavier.Vich@gmail"),Seq("OH"),       Seq("45101-9613")),
      ("Aubrey", "Fagerland",Seq(24572991),Seq("Aubrey.Fagerland"),Seq(),       Seq())).
      toDF("FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "CONFIRMATION_NUMBER", "SEGMENT_EMAIL", "SEGMENT_ADDRESS_STATE", "SEGMENT_ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE")
```

**Aggregate columns:** Now apply aggregation on desired columns to get `Seq` of `Seq`. Here is the code to do that:

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
    val df1 = df.groupBy("FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME").
          agg(collect_list("CONFIRMATION_NUMBER").as("cnlist"),
            collect_list("SEGMENT_EMAIL").as("selist"),
            collect_list("SEGMENT_ADDRESS_STATE").as("saslist"),
            collect_list("SEGMENT_ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE").as("sapclist"))
```

Here is the output of `df1`:

```
+----------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+
|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|cnlist                  |selist                                    |saslist     |sapclist                    |
+----------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+
|Stine     |Rocha    |[[48978451], [29828771]]|[[Xavier.Vich@gmail], [Xavier.Vich@gmail]]|[[MA], [OH]]|[[01545-1300], [45101-9613]]|
|Aurora    |Markusson|[[26341542]]            |[[]]                                      |[[AR]]      |[[72716]]                   |
|Aubrey    |Fagerland|[[24572991]]            |[[Aubrey.Fagerland]]                      |[[]]        |[[]]                        |
+----------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+
```

**Apply udf:** Now apply user defined function(udf) to merge array of array into single array. I've written two udf for integer and string datatype.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
 val concat_nested_string_seq:UserDefinedFunction = udf((seq_values:Seq[Seq[String]]) => {
      var output_seq:Seq[String] = Seq()
      seq_values.foreach(output_seq ++= _)
      (output_seq)
    })

  val concat_nested_integer_seq:UserDefinedFunction = udf((seq_values:Seq[Seq[Integer]]) => {
      var output_seq:Seq[Integer] = Seq()
      seq_values.foreach(output_seq ++= _)
      (output_seq)
    })
  val output_df = df1.withColumn("CONFIRMATION_NUMBER", concat_nested_integer_seq($"cnlist")).
                  withColumn("SEGMENT_EMAIL", concat_nested_string_seq($"selist")).
                  withColumn("SEGMENT_ADDRESS_STATE", concat_nested_string_seq($"saslist")).
                  withColumn("SEGMENT_ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE", concat_nested_string_seq($"sapclist")).
                  drop("cnlist", "selist", "saslist", "sapclist")
```

The `output_df` dataframe show the desired output. It also may be solved by flatting array datatype columns and then aggregating on the columns. But it might be costly operation.

Comment: Thanks, the above solution works well when the email is always the same for a first name and last name. There would be an issue when there are two records with same names but emails are different or missing. In this case, I don't want to merge the records. So is there a way to perform **groupBy** that would use the combination of (first name, last name, email) to group the records, provided that the emails are present in the column as a Sequence of Strings.